# How to put json values to Android array?

Tags: android, json

It is my json string result =

```
  {"a1":[{"Phone":"+959797715387","Pin":"744881"}],"a2":[{"Phone":"09772455728","Pin":"924543"}]}
```

and I parse the json by this code.

```
  try {
  JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(result);
  JSONObject a1  = reader.getJSONObject("a1");
  String Phone = a1.getString("Phone");
  JSONObject a2  = reader.getJSONObject("a2");
  String Pin = a2.getString("Pin");
  txv1.setText(Phone+" "+Pin);  
  }            
  catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO: handle exception
  txv1.setText("Error");
  }
```

Final Result is getting error from try/catch. Please help me to solve getting error and to store values in array. Thank you .

Comment: What is the error? Can you show me?

Comment: Why don't you catch the catch?

Comment: I got response only from catch clause. Try { is malfunctioned .

Comment: Error msg - Value[{"Phone":"+959797715387","Pin":"744881"}] at a1 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @LeonarAung try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem because the `a1` & `a2` is not JSONObject but JSONArray, so you can try this one solution:

```
public void parseJSON(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(result);

        //this for value on a1
        JSONArray a1 = reader.getJSONArray("a1");
        String Phone_a1 = a1.getJSONObject(0).getString("Phone");
        String Pin_a1 = a1.getJSONObject(0).getString("Pin");

        //this for value on a2
        JSONArray a2 = reader.getJSONArray("a2");
        String Phone_a2 = a2.getJSONObject(0).getString("Phone");
        String Pin_a2 = a2.getJSONObject(0).getString("Pin");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //your catch handle
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this

```
try {
    JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray array1 = reader.getJSONArray("a1");
    JSONObject a1_1 = array1.getJSONObject(0);
    String phone = a1_1.getString("Phone");
    String pin = a1_1.getString("Pin");
    //same thing for the object a2
} catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should understand the differences between a JSON Object and a JSON Array, here a base introduction to JSON: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Inside your json Object, a1 is an array has 1 element, so you can not get the json array by `getJSONObject` method, do `getJSONArray` instead.

MatPag has the right answer.